# How to manage memory leaks in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-leaks

Memory leaks add up over time, and if they are not cleaned up, the system eventually runs out of memory.Memory leaks are bad on any system. I want to know, how can we manage memory leaks in our C# application.

Comment: Please show an example of what you think is a memory leak in your C# application.

Comment: This question seems a little too broad. Are you talking about a specific memory leak in your code? Then please show this code or - well - fix it. Memory leaks are nothing to _manage_, but something to _avoid_.

Comment: Question is very general sort of way.

Comment: You don't 'manage' them, you prevent or solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided:

There are many kinds of memory leaks, but in general the term refer to some kind of resource that is no longer used, but still takes up memory. If you have many of those your application takes a lot of memory and eventually you run out of it.

In C#, these are some common memory leaks:

- Not removing event listeners. Any event listener that is created with
  an anonymous method or lambda expression that references an outside
  object will keep those objects alive. Remember to remove event
  listeners when they are no longer used.
- Keeping database connections or result sets open when they are not
  used. Remember to call Dispose() on all IDisposable objects. Use the
  using statement.
- Call to C functions using p/Invoke which allocate memory which you
  then never release.

Also i recommand you to read this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you research [Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx). To quote the first sentence:

> In the common language runtime (CLR), the garbage collector serves as an automatic memory manager.

As René Vogt said, it's nothing to be managed because the systems in place handle that for you.
The only thing that you need to do to *avoid* memory leakage is ensure your application will never throw an [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be done by using good development strategies and avoiding loops with unvalidated conditions to make sure it will break at some point instead of constantly creating objects until the exception is thrown.